# Creating an XML Array with sed

Tags: xml, linux, shell, sed, xmlstarlet

i'm parsing an xml file with XMLStarlet ; then i need to set that data in an xml array into another xml file .
the problem is that i didn't get the data on my final xml.

this is the xml that i'm parsing :

```
    <service>
        <position>3</position>
        <serviceType>DescriptionScrollImages</serviceType>
        <icon>gallerie_icon_.png</icon>
        <title>SERVICES</title>
        <colorTitle>#e2d5b2</colorTitle>
        <description>cipaux centres d’intérêt : des monuments, des musées ainsi que le is des congrès.</description>
        <imageScroll>
            <imageName>Photo_Gallerie_1.png</imageName>
        </imageScroll>
        <imageScroll>
            <imageName>Photo_Gallerie_2.png</imageName>
        </imageScroll>
        <imageScroll>
            <imageName>Photo_Gallerie_3.jpg</imageName>
        </imageScroll>
    </service>
```

this is my script to parse this :

**PS :servicetitle = SERVICES**, i use it in a coomment ,like a tag, because i need to insert my items just before that tag , in order.

```
s=`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(/root/services/service/imageScroll)" /home/wissem/Bureau/app.xml`

for j in `seq 1 $((s))`;
do
imagescroller=`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//root/services/service/imageScroll[$j] " -v "."  -n /home/wissem/Bureau/app.xml`| sed -i "/<\!\-\-"$servicetitle"\-\->/ i\<item>\@drawable\/'$imagescroller'<\/item>" /root/AndroidStudioProjects/RevolutionApp_T1/app/src/main/res/values/imageviewer.xml;
cp $imagescroller /root/AndroidStudioProjects/RevolutionApp_T1/app/src/main/re/drawable-hdpi/

 done;;
```

what i have on output :

```
<array name="SERVICES">
  <item>@drawable/''</item>
  <item>@drawable/''</item>
  <item>@drawable/''</item>
  <!--SERVICES-->
</array>
<!--ENDTAG-->
```

what it should be :

```
  <array name="SERVICES">
   <item>@drawable/Photo_Gallerie_1.png</item>
   <item>@drawable/Photo_Gallerie_2.png</item>
   <item>@drawable/Photo_Gallerie_3.png</item>
  <!--SERVICES-->
 </array>
 <!--ENDTAG-->
```

Comment: Why do you use `|` in `imagescroller= ...`? Write the `sed` command in a separate line. Remove the single quotes around `/'$imagescroller'<`. Hope that should help.

Comment: i did that , the result was worse , i got only <item>@drawable/

Comment: the problem seems from the variable $imagescroller, in fact , when changed it it with the counter $j , i have a normal output !! and i got the value of the counter in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of the "." 
i removed and replace it with the node name ; that worked :and that's my code :

```
for j in `seq 1 $((s))`;
do
imagescroller=`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//root/services/service/imageScroll[$j]" -v imageName -n /home/wissem/Bureau/application.xml`;
sed -i "/<\!\-\-"$servicetitle"\-\->/ i\<item>\@drawable\/$imagescroller<\/item>" /root/AndroidStudioProjects/RevApp/app/src/main/res/values/imageviewer.xml;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t \
  -e array \
     -a name -o SERVICES -b \
     -m //imageName  \
       -e item -v 'concat("@drawable/", .)' -b \
  /home/wissem/Bureau/app.xml
```